# why django username parameters passed to urls is connecting directly and how prevent it

Tags: django

I'm trying to access to a user profil if urls parameters is profile/username
it work but i have a security problem because user is directly connected.

How i can define in django user profil access depending if user is authenticated or not

profil.html

```
{% if  user.is_authenticated %}
            <p>{{ user.username}}</p>
            <a href="">edit your profile</a>

            {% else %}
            <p>{{ user.username}}</p>
            <p>basic profile of user</p>
 {% endif%}
```

views.py

```
def profil(request,username):
    user=get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    context = {
        'user':user
    }
    return render(request, 'service/profil.html',context)
```

Comment: use [`LoginRequiredMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin)  in your views so that only logged in users have access to it. [django braces](https://django-braces.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) can be useful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem condition was

`{% if  request.user == requested_user %}
            <p>{{ requested_user.username}}</p>
            <a href="">edit your profile</a>
            {% else %}
            <p>{{ requested_user.username}}</p>
            <p>basic profile of user</p>
 {% endif%}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [login required decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator). Just add it to your view:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def profil(request, username):
...
```

Comment: The problem is even if i use login_required  the user login can access to other profil and he can edit them profies

Comment: You just need to edit your logic in your view to check if that user is allowed to do that.

Comment: i wanna give permission to user without accout to visit user profil